# Referencing a property of a double pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, networking, memory-management

A function in C that I wrote works like this:

```c
int filepath_from_request(obj **context) {
    strncpy(*context->request_filepath, *context->request,  1024)); 
}
```

The `obj` object itself is defined as

```c
typedef struct obj {
    int socket; 
    char request[1024];
    char request_filepath[1024]; 
} obj; 
...

obj *context = (obj *)malloc(sizeof(obj));
```

However, referencing `*context->request` in this way throws a fatal compile-time error, `'*ctx' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?`. Why is this the case? It would see to me that I am referencing the same object that was assigned a value to, but clearly there is something that I am not understanding about double pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `->` operator has higher precedence than the `*` operator.  This means that the compiler is applying the `->` operator to `context`, which is invalid because it is not a pointer to a structure.

You need to add parenthesis to have the `*` operator apply directly to `context`:

```
strncpy((*context)->request_filepath, (*context)->request, 1024));
```

Also, you don't actually need an extra level of indirection here.  You can change the function to take an `obj *`:

```
int filepath_from_request(obj *context) {
    strncpy(context->request_filepath, context->request,  1024)); 
}
```

And change the call to match.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an operator precedence thing. Consider (*context)->request or context[0]->request, depending on which makes more sense in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

As (*) has more precedence than (->), program is considering

```
strncpy(*context->request_filepath, *context->request
```

as

```
strncpy(*(context->request_filepath), *context->request
```

And showing a fatal error to you. You can change precedence by applying the bracket as

```
strncpy((*context)->request_filepath, *context->request
```

And your job is done.